# How can I refer to my mysql container in the same pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a Kubernetes deployment.yml file that includes a container setup for:

- nginx
- php-fpm
- mysql

I have some environment variables set for my php-fpm container:

- DB_HOST
- DB_DATABASE
- DB_USER
- DB_PASSWORD

I'm wondering how I can set the DB_HOST env var to link to my MySQL container (running in the same pod as my nginx & php-fpm containers).

Or should I create a new pod for my MySQL container as then I can create a 'service' from that pod and refer to the MySQL service name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a real bad practice to setup 2 'business' container in one pod (scale you stuff individually is better than scaling everything, pod can be started on different host, ...).

Anyway, a pod share network across the container, so you can use `localhost` as hostname if you really want to set everything in one pod.

But yes it is really better to set 1 statefulset for mysql and use the name in php-fpm

Comment: Thanks, I've created different deployment yml files in order to have multiple pods & services. I can refer to the mysql service in my deployment.yml file now (the one that contains the php-fpm functionality)